# perfect powers and perfect numbers

Tags: perfect-numbers, perfect-powers

The observation that 28 = 27 + 1  shows that it is possible to have consecutive perfect powers and perfect numbers .  However, this must be very rare.  Is it unique ?

Questions: $\;$1) Are there any other examples of this which are known? $\;$$\,$2) Is there a rigorous or heuristic proof that there are only a finite number of instances of consecutive perfect powers and perfect numbers ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean anything other than "degree greater than 1" when you say a "perfect power"?

Comment: Your observation looks a lot like the big law of small numbers to me ...

Comment: Hi @user2052.  I believe your question can be settled by using the following facts:  (1)  If $N \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $N$ is not perfect;  (2)  If $N$ is an odd perfect number, then $N \equiv 1 \pmod 4$;  and (3)  If $N \neq 6$ is an even perfect number, then $N \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  However, I do not currently have a complete proof.

Comment: Also asked in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/299259.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer.

No odd perfect numbers are currently known, so I will focus on even perfect numbers.

An even perfect number $M$ is given by
$$M = 2^{p-1}\left(2^p - 1\right)$$
where $2^p - 1$ (and therefore $p$) is prime.

We compute that:
$$M + 1 = 2^{2p-1} - 2^{p-1} + 1$$
$$M - 1 = 2^{2p-1} - 2^{p-1} - 1$$

For $p = 2$, we have
$$M + 1 = 7$$
$$M - 1 = 5,$$
which are not perfect powers $q^k, r^s$ for primes $q, r$ and integers $k, s \geq 2$.

Hence we have $p$ an odd prime (since $2^p - 1$ is a *Mersenne prime*), which gives
$$M + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$
$$M - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$$
from which we obtain $M \pm 1 \ne 2^t$, for $t \geq 1$.

**Added June 21 2016**

Since $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$, we also have
$$M + 1 = 2^{2p-1} - 2^{p-1} + 1 \equiv -1 - 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$
$$M - 1 = 2^{2p-1} - 2^{p-1} - 1 \equiv -1 - 1 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3,$$
while
$$M - 1 \equiv (-7)^{2p-1} - (-7)^{p-1} - 1 \pmod 9$$
which is equivalent to
$$M - 1 \equiv -{7^{2p-1}} - 7^{p-1} - 1 \pmod 9.$$
Suppose that $M - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 9$, so that
$${7^{2p-1}} + 7^{p-1} = 7^{p-1}\left(7^p + 1\right) \equiv 8 \pmod 9.$$
This last congruence is satisfied, for example, by $p = 3$.

Nonetheless, we obtain that $M + 1 \ne 3^u$, for $u \geq 1$.